# 9patch stretches vertically, but does not horizontally

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, nine-patch

I created a 9patch image and somehow it does only stretch vertically.
I tried other 9-patch images, but they have the same effect, whyle they work in other situations. So the 9patch should be fine I think.
This is my XML code:

```
..
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottombar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/bar" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Anybody had the same issue and know how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are sure that the `height` of your `View` is really taller than the current `image` (as the others have suggested) then you should change your `ImageViews` `scaleType`. The default is `FIT_CENTER` which does not stretch the image, you should set it to `FIT_XY`.

Also you may try to set your 9-png file as the background of your `ImageView` not as the `src` and I think this will also stretch the file.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the background, but indeed I think it´s the scaleType. Was already figuring it out for hours!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a black dot to the top dead center as well as the left side center?

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be in `layout_width="match_parent"` you have mentioned width to match parent this may be the reason of 9 patch image to stretch vertically. But for height you have written `height="wrap_content"` So it doesnt stretch in height

Answer (score 0):

You have `wrap_content` specified for the height. Are you sure the content is tall enough to make the image stretch?